How to get the xpath to elements in the Table which is inside <li> tag?
I am trying to send a text into a search box which will auto list the items matching the text . I want to select the records which is exactly matching the search text..
Example:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Test Selection</title></head>
<body>
    <ul id='navlist'>
<li>
 <table style='border:1px solid black'><tr><td>1234</td><td>Johnas</td><td>Active</td></tr></table>
 </li>
 <li>
 <table style='border:1px solid blue'><tr><td>0234</td><td>Philips</td><td>Active</td></tr></table>
</li>
<li>
<table style='border:1px solid green'><tr><td>2235</td><td>Joseph</td><td>InActive</td></tr></table>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>

When I send the text 0234, it lists two records  1234 and 0234 . But I want select the second i.e 0234 alone.
I am able to select the first records using the xpath  = "//ul/li/table", but finding it difficult to locate the records exactly matching the sent text.
tried, contains(.,'0234'), contains(text()='0234'), contains(Text()='0234') . But not working.
Does contains text() also checks for numeric.

Your html contains unclosed <tr> tags. If you close them properly, something like contains(.,'0234') should work.

@JackFleeting, I will try this and update u.

I would use something like //ul/li[table//tr/td[1] = '0234'] to select the li element that contains a table with the first td of a row having the value 0234.
Example fiddle.

I don't know why you had two results for your query, but perhaps you made a mistake and queried for the string 234 rather than 0234.
To search for table elements which contain a particular piece of text which might be spread throughout the entire table, including text that begins in one table cell and continues in another, you would use this:
/html/body/ul/li/table[contains(., '0234')]

In that expression, the expression contains(., '0234') passes the table element as the first parameter of the contains function. Because the contains function expects a string value, this has the effect of converting the entire table element to a string value, by concatenating all the element's descendant text nodes, e.g. for the tables in your examples the tests would effectively be:
contains('1234JohnasActive', '0234'),
contains('0234PhilipsActive', '0234'),
contains('2235JosephInActive', '0234')

Another approach would be to check if any one of the cells in the table match the search string individually:
/html/body/ul/li/table[.//td[contains(., '0234')]]

This expression would check each table by finding all the descendant td elements, and seeing if any of them contained the string 0234. e.g. the tests would be:
contains('1234', '0234'),
contains('Johnas', '0234'),
contains('Active', '0234'),
contains('0234', '0234'),
contains('Philips', '0234'),
contains('Active', '0234'),
contains('2235', '0234'),
contains('Joseph', '0234'),
contains('InActive', '0234')

If you actually want to check if there's an exact match between your search string and any of the cells in a table, then you should use the = operator rather than the contains() function, e.g.
/html/body/ul/li/table[.//td='0234']


The effective tests would be, for table 1:
'1234'='0234',
'Johnas'='0234',
'Active'='0234'

... for table 2 only one test would be performed, because the first td in the table would return true() and the other cells would not need to be checked.
'0234'='0234'

... for table 3:
'2235'='0234',
'Joseph'='0234',
'InActive'='0234'

Note that when using the contains() function, the values are treated as strings, not as numeric values, because the contains() function expects string-valued parameters.
However, it's different when you compare an element to another value using the = operator. The = operator will have the effect of converting the element into a data type which matches the data type of the other operand. If you compare the element to a string, the test will be string equality, but if you compare it to a number, the test will be numeric equality. e.g. This expression will return the second table (because its descendant <td>0234</td> will be converted to the number 234 by the = operator).
/html/body/ul/li/table[.//td=234]

... but the following expression will not return anything, because the = operator will convert the <td>0234</td> into the string 0234, which is not equal to the string 234:
/html/body/ul/li/table[.//td='234']

